# How to put an image on another image

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have the following script

```
<div class="left">
<img src="image1.jpg" height="186" width="160" /> 
</div>

<div class="center">
<img src="image2.jpg" height="186" width="160" /> 
</div>

<div class="right">
<img src="image3.jpg" height="186" width="160" /> 
</div>
```

which generates the following :
[image: Figure-2]

I have this simple form to upload an image:

```
<form action="upload/image" method="post">
<input type="file" name="upload_image" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The reason to upload an image is to see how the mug(above) would look like with the image.

Now after uploading the image the mugs would look like following 
[image: Figure-2(After uploading image)]

Figure-2

Now if you kindly take a closer look at the above image you will see the uploaded image is sticked with the mug in such a way that as if it was designed with Photoshop but actually it was not .

Now my question is would you please kindly tell me how to paste the uploaded image on to all the three images of the coffee mug and make them look like the figure-2.

Thanks in Advance :)

P.S
I got the idea from this site-> http://www.zazzle.com/cr/design/pt-mug

I am trying to achieve the same thing the website has(I have been trying for so long but yet no result...  failing to put the the uploaded image on the images of the mug ).

Here's the download link for the image I used here http://i43.tinypic.com/d66h4.png

Comment: It works fine... (also [identical code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276190/how-to-let-users-put-text-on-an-image) wth)

Comment: Is the link you provided your site, or is it just an example your trying to replicate

Comment: Well, that's just not possible in css given that Skype image! You'll have to create a faux-effect with transparency in Gimp or PS and absolute position the uploaded image and adjust it px by px.

Comment: @DrewGalbraith Thanks for your reply. The link I provided is not my site, I am just trying to replicate it. :) I have edited my question to remove the confusion. Thanks :)

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not possible with html, javascript, and css as @elclanrs said. From the requests made by the page, it would appear that this site is using a dll to render the images. In all likeliness it is using some 3rd party program or code they wrote in a language such as c or c++

Comment: @Purmou . Thanks for your reply. You found my code identical with code from another post because, the post you refer to here is also my question but from another account. The other day I asked a question which some code experts thought not appropriate for stackoverflow.com and so down voted the question ; as a result I cannot ask anymore question using that account and I had to open a new account. I have edited the question today but still cannot ask questions :(

Comment: @Drew Galbraith Thanks again for your reply. :) I guess an alternative solution to my problem would be Flash.

Comment: You could use html5 canvas or webgl. A 3d model of the mug and a texture will do.

Comment: @elclanrs. I have heard about html5 canvas but I have no idea about webgl. I guess I have to learn both html5 and webgl first to get my solution. :( thanks

Comment: hotspots can also do this for you without any worries you just need to find corect coordinate in the mug image then a i think that portion of the image can be used to show another image on it

Comment: first of all you need to put your mug base images as background so that uploaded image will be the overlay of that and with the help of  "GDlibrary" functions/methods you can adjust the position and the size of uploaded image as shown in fig2.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this.

If you examine the given url from Zazzle.com, after uploading the image, it is calling a program on their server - "designall.dll". It is doing all the magic.

As our other friends mentioned, it is not possible to achieve that effect simply with HTML, CSS and JavaScript (without using Canvas).

But using some server side program you can achieve this without any issues.

As I program on LAMP, I am giving a solution to implement the same with PHP and ImageMagick.

- User uploads an image.
- Image will be sent to a back-end PHP file.
- PHP will distort the image as per our requirements.
- Creates three copies and store in a temp folder with some unique ID.
- As a response to that we will get some success code.
- Once we get a success code, we will load the images from temp folder.
- As the user clicks on any type of image, we will update the image as required.

And regarding the actual distortion code, you can use ImageMagick plugin.

More information about ImageMagick plugin can be found at :
[ImageMagick Website](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

More information about the ways to distort (actually wrapping) an image using ImageMagick can be found at : [Wrapping](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/warping/) and [Distrotion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/). These links contain good number of examples with preview too.

For our example, we need to create some static code which will distort an image every time in same shape.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Friends, please help "black_belt" with better solutions if any.

Thanks.

Comment: "it is not possible to achieve that effect simply with HTML, CSS and JavaScript." I would disagree greatly. Javascript and canvas can be pretty damn powerful

Comment: Yes, I agree with AlanFoster. It is not possible to achieve that effect simply with HTML, CSS and JavaScript without using Canvas. Sorry for the confusion.