# How to transform an image in html5 and canvas so to that it fits on a 3d mesh?

Tags: html, canvas

This question is an extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338891/how-to-put-an-image-on-another-image). How it can be done using canvas and html5. I dont only want to just wrap an image around an object. I want it to transform with respect to a 3d mesh like grid. Can someone guide me please?
[3d mesh like grid jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKn0v.jpg)
[image wrapped on an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydYBo.png)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I dont know where to start. I dont want the problem solved and given to me on a plate. I just want to know the terms and some direction where I can move. Thanks.